# Why is RTTI needed for non-polymorphic typeid?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, rtti

I have the following piece of code :

```
template<typename T>
class genericHandler{public: using evt_t = T;};

template<typename T>
class specialHandler : public genericHandler<T> {  /* more stuff */ };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    std::any any_var = specialHandler<int>{};
    
    auto f = [&any_var](auto evtHandler) {
        using EventType = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(evtHandler)>::type ::evt_t;
        if(any_var.type() == typeid(EventType)) { std::cout << "yes" << std::endl; } else { std::cout << "no" << std::endl; }
    };

    auto h = specialHandler<int>{ };
    f(h);
}
```

[Try it on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b57345d69f9b6085)

When called, `evtHandler` is of non-polymorphic derived type `specialHandler`. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), we have :

> When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a
> typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table
> lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time.

When I compile with gcc and `-fno-rtti`, I get the following error message :

> cannot use 'typeid' with '-fno-rtti'

**RTTI is run-time type information, which should not be needed in the case of non-polymorphic typeid that can be deduced at compile-time. Did I miss something ?**

Comment: Your type is non-polymorphic but unfortunately you cannot know it about `std::any`'s internals.

Comment: Compare http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1105r1.html. I can confirm that it works with VS2017 (and rtti disabled), but fails on gcc trunk and clang trunk.

Comment: GCC's `std::any`works fine without RTTI, just use `any_cast` to check if it holds that type, instead of using `typeid`, e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68faa89814ea711

Comment: In comment under answer you have wrote something about dependency cycle. Please describe this problem since apparently this is actual source of your problems and there are many tricks to break such cycle.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking two questions.

1. > **RTTI is run-time type information, which should not be needed in the case of non-polymorphic typeid ...**

   But this is a compiler switch, not a language feature, so you should check the [compiler documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno-rtti):

   > -fno-rtti
   >
   > Disable generation of information about every class with virtual functions for use by the C++ runtime type identification features (`dynamic_cast` and `typeid`). **If you don't use those parts of the language, you can save some space by using this flag**. Note that exception handling uses the same information, but it will generate it as needed. The `dynamic_cast` operator can still be used for casts that do not require runtime type information, i.e. casts to void * or to unambiguous base classes.

   (my emphasis).

   So the switch disables the entire typeinfo system to save space. If you want `typeinfo` (or you want to use a standard library facility that uses `typeinfo`), then don't explicitly disable `typeinfo` with a compiler option.
2. > **... non-polymorphic typeid that can be deduced at compile-time**

   Edit, as Mr. Wakely points out, the issue is that you're explicitly using `typeid` in your own code.

   Although `std::any` may be capable of erasing the stored type from the top-level object without RTTI, this is implementation-dependent, and it *definitely* can't implement `std::any::type()` without using the `typeid`/`typeinfo` you told GCC not to generate.

Oh, and I forgot

3. > **Did I miss something ?**

   Yes, to ask your actual question, which is

   > I'm erasing it because I need to solve a circular template dependency, sadly I am not free to 'simply not erase it' here. **Do I have any alternative that doesn't use RTTI**

   Sure, type erasure doesn't depend on RTTI.

   Only *automated* type erasure depends on RTTI and, as above, not all of that. You can either avoid `std::any::type()` or write your own discriminated union by hand - you'd need to enumerate your types, but only the enumeration itself needs to be visible to all users of the DU.

Comment: I'm erasing it because I need to solve a circular template dependency, sadly I am not free to 'simply not erase it' here. Do I have any alternative that doesn't use RTTI ?

Comment: That answer does not explain why `typeid(EventType)` does not work. `EventType` is known at compile time to be `int`. [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) say that `-fno-rtti` *Disable generation of information about every class with virtual functions*, but `int` has no virtual functions.

Comment: @WernerHenze But it also says "If you don't use those parts of the language" - meaning `dynamic_cast` except as specifically allowed and `typeid` - then you can use the -fno-rtti flag. Implying it can't be used if `typeid` is needed at all.

Comment: @Magix `std::any` is rather tied to `typeid` and RTTI. I'd suggest opening another question about potential alternatives, with more context for why `std::any` seemed to be appropriate or necessary.

Comment: The answer does explicitly answer why `typeid` does not work. It's because the GCC flag disables the whole `typeinfo` system. I'm really not sure how much clearer I can be. If you don't like the GCC doc itself, take it up with them.

Comment: @Magix `EventType` is known to be `int` but `typeid` returns a `std::typeinfo` object, and then you try to compare that to another `std::typeinfo` object. Where do you expect those objects to come from if you've told the compiler you don't need them? It's irrelevant that `typeid(int)` is known at compile-time when the `==` comparison is a run-time operation, and for it to work there has to be a pair of `std::typeinfo` objects in the first place.

Comment: @aschepler `std::any` is not tied to RTTI at all, only `std::any::type` *must* use it. As I commented above, GCC's `std::any`works fine without RTTI, e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68faa89814ea711

Comment: Any circular dependency is problem of code design. It should be fixed by breaking cycle, not by doping some functionality like RTTI. This can be achieved by extracting some common dependency which creates cycle. For example split some class into two classes.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: "*std::any is not tied to RTTI at all, only std::any::type must use it.*" No, all forms of `any_cast` must also use RTTI. They are *required* to fail (either via exception or a null pointer) if the given type does not match the stored one. You can implement `any` in such a way that it doesn't fail on mismatches, but that wouldn't comply with the standard. Of course, neither does turning off RTTI to begin with, so...

Comment: @NicolBolas, you can implement it so it fails on mismatches without RTTI. Look at my coliru example, it is compiled with `-fno-rtti` and returns a null pointer when the type doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to altered your code not use `std::any::type()`. In such case everything works as expected (after fixing some other issue in your code):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

template<typename T>
class genericHandler{public: using evt_t = T;};

template<typename T>
class specialHandler : public genericHandler<T> {  /* more stuff */ };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    std::any any_var = specialHandler<int>{};
    
    auto f = [&any_var](auto evtHandler) {
        using EventType = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(evtHandler)>::type ::evt_t;
        std::cout << (std::any_cast<specialHandler<EventType>>(&any_var) != nullptr ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
    };

    auto h = specialHandler<int>{ };
    f(h);
    f(specialHandler<double>{});
}
```

Works when RTTI is disabled:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20855b15701605f1